# Idempotency check in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

Does anybody know how to insert into Neo4J based on the existing data? This is part of data ingestion.

For example, there is already a node in neo4j with an attribute `updatedAt`. Whenever a new pubsub event to ingest data is received, I need to check for the `updatedAt` attribute of both incoming data and the existing node in neo4j and decide which data needs to be discarded.

In the end, neo4j should have a node with the latest `updatedAt` value.

Is there any way other than Triggers, APOC?

Please help. I am really new to Neo4j. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is Cypher [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) query and more precisely `MERGE` query with `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH`. For example:

```
MERGE (n:TYPE_OF_NODE { id: 'ID_OF_NODE_TO_BE_FOUND' })
ON CREATE SET 
    n.createdAt = INPUT_DATE,
    .../* Set other attributes if needed */
ON MATCH SET n.updatedAt = 
    CASE WHEN n.updatedAt < INPUT_DATE THEN INPUT_DATE ELSE n.updatedAt END,
    ... /* Set other attributes if needed */
RETURN n
```

The query above checks if a node of a given type *TYPE_OF_NODE* and with `id` equal to *ID_OF_NODE_TO_BE_FOUND* exists. By *INPUT_DATE* I mean some date that was received together with an event to ingest data.

1. If a node does not exist, it will be created and some attributes will be set
   (see `ON CREATE SET`).
2. If it exists, then it will be updated (see
   `ON MATCH SET`). Specifically, `updateAt` attribute will be set to
   the later value and for that I used `CASE` statement.

Comment: this is a good solution but is there a way that I can update all properties in one go. Instead of updating it one by one

Comment: I found out a solution using [Neo4J APOC Library](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/). Using `apoc.do.when`.

Comment: @RahulThampiT Can you paste a snippet showing how you want to use apod.do.when?

Comment: Apologies, I made an update in query now, I'm currently using `apoc.do.case` query 

`OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Node {<conditions>}) 
CALL apoc.do.case(
[
n IS NULL ,"CREATE(m:Node) SET <properties to be set> RETURN m",
n IS NOT NULL AND n.updated_at<"2020-05-08T07:59:04.887Z", "SET <properties to be set> RETURN n"
],
"RETURN n", { n:n })
YIELD value
RETURN value`